# Why isn't my layout-large folder being accessed?

Tags: android, android-layout

The class below never invokes the layout that is in the layout-large folder. That is the maintabletlayout.xml file below. I'm using an avd that has a resolution of 800x1280 and has a density of 160. The findViewById() below always returns null. Any ideas? What specs does the system have to have to access the layout-large folder?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
 boolean mTwoPane;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<String> subjects=new ArrayList<String>();
    subjects.add("Math");
    subjects.add("Science");
    subjects.add("Art");
    if(findViewById(R.id.top_tablet_container)!=null){
       mTwoPane=true; 
    }else{
        mTwoPane=false;
    }

    if(mTwoPane){
        setContentView(R.layout.maintabletlayout);
        SubjectListFragment top=new SubjectListFragment(subjects,mTwoPane);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.list_container, top).commit();
    }else{

        setContentView(R.layout.mainphonelayout);
        SubjectListFragment top=new SubjectListFragment(subjects,mTwoPane);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.top_phone_container, top).commit();

    }
}
}
```

mainphonelayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/top_phone_container"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

</LinearLayout>
```

maintabletlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/top_tablet_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/content_container"
  >


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@id/content_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/content_container"
  >

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the manifest I also have this

```
<supports-screens
   android:xlargeScreens="true"
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:anyDensity="true" />
```

@nOiAd had the correct answer. I had to give both layouts the same name and then setContentView() with that name. That way you set the content view for the appropriate size screen and then findViewById() is able to return non null when trying to find an id in the large screen layout.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ArrayList<String> subjects=new ArrayList<String>();
        subjects.add("Math");
        subjects.add("Science");
        subjects.add("Art");
        if(findViewById(R.id.top_tablet_container)!=null){
           mTwoPane=true; 
        }else{
            mTwoPane=false;
        }

        if(mTwoPane){

            SubjectListFragment top=new SubjectListFragment(subjects,mTwoPane);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.list_container, top).commit();
        }else{


            SubjectListFragment top=new SubjectListFragment(subjects,mTwoPane);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.top_phone_container, top).commit();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try higher density like 300 ?

Comment: findViewById() will always return null because you didnt show any before.

Comment: this views id should only be present with a large device, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nOiAd had the correct answer. I had to give both layouts the same name and then setContentView() with that name. That way you set the content view for the appropriate size screen and then findViewById() is able to return non null when trying to find an id in the large screen layout.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ArrayList<String> subjects=new ArrayList<String>();
        subjects.add("Math");
        subjects.add("Science");
        subjects.add("Art");
        if(findViewById(R.id.top_tablet_container)!=null){
           mTwoPane=true; 
        }else{
            mTwoPane=false;
        }

        if(mTwoPane){

            SubjectListFragment top=new SubjectListFragment(subjects,mTwoPane);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.list_container, top).commit();
        }else{


            SubjectListFragment top=new SubjectListFragment(subjects,mTwoPane);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.top_phone_container, top).commit();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 3.2 you should use `layout-swXXXdp` notation, where `XXX` is number. In your case should be `720`, a 10" screen

Comment: Why does 720 designate a 10 inch screen? I'm using a 7 inch avd and changed my folder to the name you suggested and I'm having no luck. I also tried layout-sw800dp and layout-sw600dp with no luck.

Comment: it is in android documentation. sw600dp is for  7 inch. what values did  you give to minSdkVersion and targetSkdVersion?

Comment: here the doc: http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: Thanks for that, I've added the xlargeScreens attribute to the manifest and renamed the folder to be layout-sw800dp for my 800x1280 display. Still not working.

Comment: according with the documentation it should be layout-sw720dp

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the emulator you are running indeed has been configured to be "large". The range of resolutions doesn't automatically applies on the size "bucket" (normal/large/...).
[image: Emulators]

Comment: I'm using a cloned nexus 7 avd with no luck